# Help with economics graph

Tags: diagrams, plot

I am new to LaTeX, but I need to draw this 2 period model. Thank you in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello Dinara and welcome to TeX.SX! One question: what does the crossed out lines mean?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This site is full of very similar plots. I guess the least thing you should do is to provide the information how the curves are determined. Do you have functions for them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is really cumbersome trying to decipher your scan.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.44,>=latex,declare
function={f(\x)=0.5*cos(2*deg(\x-0.8))-0.4*\x+pi;}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{(pi/180)*atan(2/(3*pi))/2}
 \draw[thick,latex-latex,name path=axes] (0,5)node[below left]{$t_1$} -- (0,0) coordinate(O) -- (7,0) node[below left]{$t_2$};
 \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,samples=30,variable=\x,domain=0:2.2]
 ({\x},{f(\x)}) coordinate(x1);
 \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,samples=30,variable=\x,domain=4.5:6.5]
 ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[red,thick,postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=% actually add a mark
      between positions 0.1 and 0.9 step 5pt
      with
      {
        \draw[black,thin] (-2pt,2pt) -- (2pt,-2pt);
      }}] (0.8+\DeltaX,{f(0.8+\DeltaX)}) coordinate (x2) 
      -- (0.8+1.5*pi-\DeltaX,{f(0.8+1.5*pi-\DeltaX)}) coordinate(x3)
      coordinate[pos=-0.5](xm) coordinate[pos=1.5](xp);
 \path[name path=extension] (xm) -- (xp);     
 \draw[red,name intersections={of=axes and extension}]
 (intersection-1) -- (x2) (intersection-2) -- (x3);
 \fill[red]  (x2) circle(1.5pt) (x3) circle(1.5pt);
 \draw[dashed] (O |- x1) node[left]{$\ell_1$} -| (O -|x1) node[below]{$\ell_0$};
 \draw[dashed] (-1,0 |- x2) coordinate(y2a) -| (0,-0.5 -|x2) coordinate(y2b);
 \draw[dashed] (O) -- (0,-1) coordinate (y3);
 \draw[dashed] (-1,0 |- x3) --(O |- x3) node[left,fill=white]{$x_1$} -| (y3-|x3);
 \draw[<->] (y2a) -- (y2a|-x3) node[midway,left]{$y$};
 \draw[<->] (y2b) -- (y2b-|x1) node[midway,below]{$z$};
 \draw[<->] (y3) -- (y3-|x3) node[midway,below]{$x_0$};
 % additional request
 \path (y2a) -- (y2a-|0,0) coordinate[midway] (y2c);
 \draw[<->] (y2c) -- (y2c|-x1) node[midway,fill=white]{$f(z)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}
\begin{document}
\section*{A short note on a somewhat more systematic construction of such plots}

The function you want to plot seems to have two branches with local maxima. We
are interested in constructing something that resembles that with little effort.
The basic observation is that the plot looks like a superpostion of 
a cosine and some line with constant negative slope, and some part omitted, as
sketched in Figure~\ref{fig:ansatz}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.5*cos(3*deg(\x-0.8));
g(\x)=0.5*cos(3*deg(\x-0.8))-0.4*\x;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{(pi/180)*atan(2/(3*pi))/3}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
 \draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.5*pi,smooth,samples=90] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[red] (0.8+\DeltaX,{f(0.8+\DeltaX)}) -- (0.8+pi-\DeltaX,{f(0.8+pi-\DeltaX)});
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=right,xshift=6cm]
 \draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.5*pi,smooth,samples=90]
 ({\x},{g(\x)});
 \draw[red] (0.8+\DeltaX,{g(0.8+\DeltaX)}) -- (0.8+pi-\DeltaX,{g(0.8+pi-\DeltaX)});
\end{scope} 
\draw[ultra thick,-latex] (left.south east) -- (left.south east -| right.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Motivation of the ansatz.}
\label{fig:ansatz}
\end{figure}

This suggests an ansatz of the form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ansatz}
 f(x)~=~a\,\cos[b\,(x-x_0)]+c\,x+d\;.
\end{equation} 
The slope of this function is periodic with period $2\pi/b$. The slope of the
point slightly right of the left maximum, i.e.\ at $x=x_1=x_0+\Delta x$, and the
slope of the point slightly left of the right minimum, i.e.\ at
$x=x_2=x_0+\frac{3\pi}{b}-\Delta x$, coincide by construction. $\Delta x$ is
determined by the requirement that 
\[ f'(x_1)~=~-a\,b\,\sin(b\,\Delta x)~\stackrel{!}{=}~
-\frac{2a\,\cos(b\,\Delta x)}{3\pi/b}~=~-2a\,b\,\frac{\cos(b\,\Delta x)}{3\pi}\;,\]
which fixes 
\[
 \Delta x~=~\frac{1}{b}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{3\pi}\right)\;.
\]
With all these preparations one only needs to adjust the parameters in
\eqref{eq:ansatz} to change the appearance of the plot without losing the
features.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.44,>=latex,declare
function={f(\x)=0.5*cos(2*deg(\x-0.8))-0.4*\x+pi;}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{(pi/180)*atan(2/(3*pi))/2}
 \draw[thick,latex-latex,name path=axes] (0,5)node[below left]{$t_1$} -- (0,0) coordinate(O) -- (7,0) node[below left]{$t_2$};
 \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,samples=30,variable=\x,domain=0:2.2]
 ({\x},{f(\x)}) coordinate(x1);
 \draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth,samples=30,variable=\x,domain=4.5:6.5]
 ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[red,thick,postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=% actually add a mark
      between positions 0.1 and 0.9 step 5pt
      with
      {
        \draw[black,thin] (-2pt,2pt) -- (2pt,-2pt);
      }}] (0.8+\DeltaX,{f(0.8+\DeltaX)}) coordinate (x2) 
      -- (0.8+1.5*pi-\DeltaX,{f(0.8+1.5*pi-\DeltaX)}) coordinate(x3)
      coordinate[pos=-0.5](xm) coordinate[pos=1.5](xp);
 \path[name path=extension] (xm) -- (xp);     
 \draw[red,name intersections={of=axes and extension}]
 (intersection-1) -- (x2) (intersection-2) -- (x3);
 \fill[red]  (x2) circle(1.5pt) (x3) circle(1.5pt);
 \draw[dashed] (O |- x1) node[left]{$\ell_1$} -| (O -|x1) node[below]{$\ell_0$};
 \draw[dashed] (-1,0 |- x2) coordinate(y2a) -| (0,-0.5 -|x2) coordinate(y2b);
 \draw[dashed] (O) -- (0,-1) coordinate (y3);
 \draw[dashed] (-1,0 |- x3) --(O |- x3) node[left,fill=white]{$x_1$} -| (y3-|x3);
 \draw[<->] (y2a) -- (y2a|-x3) node[midway,left]{$y$};
 \draw[<->] (y2b) -- (y2b-|x1) node[midway,below]{$z$};
 \draw[<->] (y3) -- (y3-|x3) node[midway,below]{$x_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Result.}
\label{fig:result}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Say, if i want to add one more <-> from end of y to l1, i use: \draw[<->] (y2a) -- (y2a|-x1) node[midway,below]{$f(z)$}; but than it overlays {y}, how to i move it a bit closer to graph maybe?

Comment: @Dinara I just added a short note on a somewhat more systematic construction of such figures. Does the resulting figure fulfill your requirements? I'd do `\path (y2a) -- (y2a-|0,0) coordinate[midway] (y2c);
 \draw[<->] (y2c) -- (y2c|-x1) node[midway,fill=white]{$f(z)$};`.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. If now I want to more the lowest curve up, do i change the whole expression of (g(x))?

Comment: @Dinara Yes, you only need to adjust the function, e.g. `declare
function={f(\x)=0.5*cos(2*deg(\x-0.8))-0.4*\x+pi+1;}`, where I added `+1` in order to move the graph up by one.